# Get the default webpage file name

Tags: ruby, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

Is there a way to get the default web page of a given url in ruby?

I'm looking for a function like

```
get_indexpage_for("www.example.com")
```

with a result that's equal to something like

```
'index.html' or 'index.php' or 'index.htm' or ...
```

Even the HTTP-header doesn't contain this information and i've also looked at the Net::HTTP class but i couldn't find a solution.
Can someone pls help?

Comment: No. As you've discovered, this information is not reported in the HTTP headers, and there's not another way to get it. Can you clarify what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want to get the index file to complete a given relative path. If i have e.g. a link with the href attribute '?page=login' i want to complete this relative path to 'www.example.com/index.php?page=login'. I know that 'www.example.com/?page=login' is a valid path but the whole path including the index file looks a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it if there actually is a url that can be discerned. It works like a charm on some pages and not on others.

It should work on the url I've used in my example...

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'pp'

agent = Mechanize.new

login_url = 'http://www.reports.rtui.com'

page = agent.get(login_url)
puts page.uri
```

index.html is the standard default, but if you go to google.com they don't appear to have an index page. Instead it runs more like an application, serving content as its requested.

I'm no pro by any measure, but based on my research there doesn't seem to be one magic bullet that does what you want. At least, not one that's obvious. It really depends on the page itself.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but that's not working for me. It always returns the url i've defined in login_url without any file-extension.

Comment: Not that it will solve your problem, but you might get some additional info by changing the last line of my example to "puts page.headers"

Comment: Like i wrote in the question, i've already tried to get the info from the returned http-header. But all webpages i''ve tested don't send this information in their headers. Even the url you've mentioned above didn't work for me (resolve error).